# Why does Math#nextUp not increment by Double.MIN_VALUE?

Tags: java, math, floating-point

I learned this from the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp(double))

It basically says that:

> Returns the floating-point value adjacent to d in the direction of positive infinity.

and especially:

> If the argument is zero, the result is Double.MIN_VALUE

With this logic:

`Math.nextUp(double x) - x` should always be `Double.MIN_VALUE`.

So I tested it out:

```
double d_up = Math.nextUp(0);
System.out.println(d_up);                        // 1.401298464324817E-45
System.out.println(d_up == Double.MIN_VALUE);    // false
System.out.println(Double.MIN_VALUE);            // 4.9E-324
```

and it doesn't even work with zero.

Why does `Math.nextUp(double x)` not equal `x + Double.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: You're getting `Float.MIN_VALUE`. This method is overloaded in the `Math` class.

Comment: You're calling Math.nextUp(Float x).

Comment: I just read the title... So you were expecting `Float.MIN_VALUE` but you're still surprised by the results?

Comment: @Gendarme  But it seems that only worked for 0.0, not other values. I thought `Math.nextUp(double x) == double x + Double.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: For what value does it not work?

Comment: @Gendarme  I thought for any `value`, it should be returning the `value + Double.MIN_VALUE`. but it is not true. For example, `Math.nextUp(1.5d) - 1.5d;`

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't? Demonstrate that in your question; not in the comments.

Comment: "Math.nextUp(double x) - double x should always be Double.MIN_VALUE" — Your assumption would only be correct if all doubles were evenly spaced, but of course they are not.

Comment: @Gendarme Already demonstrated it in the line "With this Logic:" and after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
double d_up = Math.nextUp(0d); // see the little `d` there :)
```

Or this, it works as well:

```
double d_up = Math.nextUp(0.0); // `0.0` is a `double` literal
```

You need to pass a *double* for the advertised contract to work. Now your test works!

```
4.9E-324
true
4.9E-324
```

Just to be clear, you were passing a `float` before, so this was the method that got executed:

```
public static float nextUp​(float f)
```

... And naturally, that one returns `Float.MIN_VALUE` when `0` (an `int`) is passed as a parameter, because it gets automatically casted to a `float`. Bottom line: mind your types, make sure to cast to the right one.

Regarding the last part of your question, there's no reason why this equation should work: `Math.nextUp(x) - x == Double.MIN_VALUE`. `double` numbers are not evenly spaced, the "distance" between any two numbers is not necessarily `Double.MIN_VALUE`.

This is related to the fact that decimal values in a computer cannot be represented exactly, it's all an approximation that depends on the number of bits used to represent them, and that's a finite quantity - and between any two real numbers there's an infinite number of reals.

Comment: Or use `0.0` as a `double` literal.

Comment: But what about `Math.nextUp(double x) - double x == Double.MIN_VALUE`? It doesn't seem so, only worked for 0.0

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 I don't understand _why_ that should work, the contract of the method says that it just returns the next adjacent value to "the right", why the difference w.r.t. the original value should be the `MIN_VALUE`?. It'll be a small number for sure, but not zero. The "distance" between `double` values is not a fixed, constant quantity.

Comment: But why wouldn't the next adjacent value be the `value + Double.MIN_VALUE`? The minimum value of Double offers the minimum addition to another double value. Is that logic so wrong?

Comment: Or, basically, can you describe what does adjacent mean?

Comment: It is wrong, because floating point numbers are weird in computers.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Doubles are not evenly spaced out. The larger their magnitude, the further apart they are spaced.

Comment: Think of it this way: *"Why would this method exist if it was just incrementing by `Float.MIN_VALUE`?"*

Comment: @Gendarme There could be many reasons, for example, simplify the code. Again, I am not arguing with you. I just don't understand. Because apparently another double value could exist between `value` and `Math.nextUp(value)`, so how can you claim them being adjacent.

Comment: Because `x + Float.MIN_VALUE` itself doesn't exist. That's the issue here (probably); not that there's another value in between (although that could also be the case, I suppose).

Floating point arithmethics isn't your normal mathematics. You never use floating points for exact values; that's what [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is for. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Answer (score 2):

The floating-point numbers are similar to this: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500,…

“Adjacent” means two numbers are next to each other in this list. For numbers in this list, `Math.nextup(x) - x` may produce 1, 10, or 100, depending on where in the list `x` is.